# Django drf-social-oauth2 Social Signup fallback login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-oauth

I am trying to create a SPA, and want enable to Google Sign In/Sign Up.

Is there a way to click `Sign In with Google` and:

1. First try to Sign Up
2. If the user already exists, login and return `access token` else create the user and then return the `access token`

I also use [drf-social-oauth2](https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2)

Comment: Found this from `python-social-auth` -> https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html

Answer (score 0):

I am the main maintainer of https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2. Did you try reading the README file? There are instructions there on how to authenticate with Google. There are also a few issues where people managed to use Google successfully.
Here, you can check this closed issue: https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2/issues/38.